# Как сделать фильтр товаров для интернет магазина на laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Подскажите, как сделать правильный фильтр товаров? Сейчас делаю так:

```
$select_parts = Product::select('product_manufacturer.title as manufacturer', 'product.*')->join('product_manufacturer', 'product_manufacturer.id', '=', 'product.manufacturer_id')->join('product_attribute', 'product_attribute.product_id', '=', 'product.id')->where('product.status', 1)
        ->where(function($query) use ($catalog) {
            return $query->where('product.category_id', $catalog->id)->orWhereIn('product.category_id', Catalog::where('product_category.parent_id', $catalog->id)->pluck('product_category.id'))
        })->where(function($query) use ($ar_select_properties) {
            if (isset($ar_select_properties)) {
                $query->whereIn('product_attribute.attribute_id', $ar_select_properties);
            }
        })->get();
```

Массив `$ar_select_properties` содержит id атрибутов, по которым идёт поиск.

Сейчас при фильтрации количество результатов увеличивается, хотя должно уменьшаться. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

например так :

```
protected function search(Request $request)
{
    $this->cars = Car::where('publish', true);

    if ($request->has('car_status_id') && $request->car_status_id) {
        $this->cars->where('car_status_id', $request->car_status_id);
    }

    if ($request->has('car_manufacturer_id') && $request->car_manufacturer_id) {
        $this->cars->where('car_manufacturer_id', $request->car_manufacturer_id);
    }

    if ($request->has('car_model_id') && $request->car_model_id) {
        $explode = explode(',', $request->car_model_id);
        $this->cars->whereIn('car_model_id', $explode);
    }

    if ($request->has('parking_id') && $request->parking_id) {
        $this->cars->where('parking_id', $request->parking_id);
    }

    if ($request->has('car_engine_capacity_id') && $request->car_engine_capacity_id) {
        $this->cars->where('car_engine_capacity_id', $request->car_engine_capacity_id);
    }

    if ($request->has('release_date') && $request->release_date) {
        $this->cars->where('release_date', $request->release_date);
    }

    if ($request->has('current_number') && $request->current_number) {
        $this->cars->where('current_number', $request->current_number);
    }

    if ($request->has('vin_code') && $request->vin_code) {
        $this->cars->where('vin_code', $request->vin_code);
    }

    if ($request->has('sold_at') && $request->sold_at) {
        $this->cars->whereHas('soldCar',
            function ($q) use ($request) {
                $q->whereDate('created_at', $request->sold_at);
            }
        );
    }

    $cars->paginate(15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у вас проблема с областью видимости переменной `$ar_select_properties` во второй анонимной функции. Так как эта функция вложена в первую, то в первой функции $ar_select_properties тоже должна быть определена.
У вас сейчас `isset($ar_select_properties)` всегда будет false, так как функция вообще не видит эту переменную.

Попробуйте во второй строке вместо

```
->where(function($query) use ($catalog) {
```

написать

```
->where(function($query) use ($catalog, $ar_select_properties) {
```

Comment: во второй анонимной функции у меня выбираются категории для отображения. Меня интересует, как сделать фильтр, чтобы при выборе опций товары уменьшались в количественные. Например: выбираю Диаметр: 18, Ширина профиля: 223, и должны показаться только те товары, где диаметр 18 и ширина 223. Сейчас у меня выбираются товары, где  диаметр 18 и где ширина 223

Comment: Обновил ответ. На данный момент у вас никогда не сработает `$query->whereIn('product_attribute.attribute_id', $ar_select_properties);`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в своём вопросе: сначала надо было получить все товары и атрибуты, а затем работать с коллекцией.